# how to solve IOerror (windows power shell)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Please find the code I try to run below.

```rust
extern crate image;
use image::GenericImageView;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    // Use the open function to load an image from a Path.
    // `open` returns a `DynamicImage` on success.
    let img = image::open(
        "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Multiprocessor real-time scheduling/Project2/data/aLIEz.jpg",
    )
    .unwrap();

    // The dimensions method returns the images width and height.
    println!("dimensions {:?}", img.dimensions());

    // The color method returns the image's `ColorType`.
    println!("{:?}", img.color());

    // Write the contents of this image to the Writer in PNG format.
    img.save("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Multiprocessor real-time scheduling/Project2/data/test.png")
        .unwrap();
}
```

The error I want to solve (in the last line `img.save`) :

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IoError(Os { code: 5, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Accès refusé." })', src\main.rs:18:96
```

Comment: Do you already have the destination file `test.png`? If you do, what are the access rights on it?

Comment: No, I don't have the destination file. I believe it is automatically created by the function

Comment: What are the access rights on the destination directory, then? For now error tells you that your code fails to create the file, because system doesn't allow it.

Comment: write and read are allowed in the folder

Comment: Ok, I solved the error. It was my antivirus who implictily create that error, so I add an exception of scanning in my destinaton path. Thank you